# Manipular dados no Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, typescript

Estou usando o Ionic 2 para o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo, gostaria de saber como posso usar os valores enviados de um form dentro de um método.

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateUser" (ngSubmit)="UpdateUser(displayname, email)" #upForm="ngForm">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Nome</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"  name="displayname" formControlName="displayname"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>E-mail</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="email"  formControlName="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button ion-button block [disabled]="updateUser.invalid">Atualizar Dados</button>
```

E o seguinte método dentro do meu perfil.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-perfil',
  templateUrl: 'perfil.html'
})

export class PerfilPage {
  perfis: any;
  updateUser: any = {};

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private auth: AuthProvider, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
auth.getUserData().then(data =>{
  this.perfis = data;
  this.perfis = Array.of(this.perfis);
})
this.updateUser = this.formBuilder.group({
  displayname: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]
})
  }

UpdateUser(){
  console.log(this.updateUser.value);
}

  }
```

Eu preciso pegar os valores de Display Name e Email dentro desse método, dessa forma eu só consigo ver no console, e preciso usar os valores dentro do método

Comment: Não entendi, o valor do seu form não já está sendo passado para o método através da propriedade `this.updateUser`? O que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: O valor está sendo passado, mas eu preciso pegar o valor separado de cada controlname dentro dessa função updateUser()

Comment: Adicione um atributo para cada valor na sua `PerfilPage` e faça algo como `this.displayname = this.updateUser.value.displayname` e `this.email = this.updateUser.value.email`. É isso que você precisa?